# Make Html Menu Dropdown Active

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown inside Html navbar. I want to make Dropdown Title Active, when sub-item is selected using Css.

Home
                            
                                About Us

Our Team

Here I want About Us to be highlighted when Our Team is selected using jquery and css.

My Jquery:

```
$("nav li a").each(function () {     
    if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        //alert($(this).parent().attr("Id"));
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
     }


  // else {
  //     $("li.active").removeClass("active");
  //}
});
```

Comment: can you show us your html code?

Comment: you don't necessarily need jquery to do that, you can just use for the top level title, li:hover > a for styling, then when a child is selected, you can just li li a:hover for styling, if its just for a different appearance for top levels and children your after

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on why you used each() but
since you said selected. it's safe to assume that the dropdown title gets active after click event?
if so, then you can do it like this.

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cuteporing/we7y2vvp/)**

```
$(".nav li > a").click(function () {
  if($(this).attr('role')){
    $(this).parents('li.dropdown').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }else{
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

if not then [Crispy George's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699411/crispy-george) answer might be the one you're looking for